# cannot call method 'on' of undefined at object

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, chat

When I try to run node app.js in my node.js command prompt, I get an error saying

```
cannot call method 'on' of undefined at object
```

Here's my code:

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
server = require('http').createServer(app),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

    server.listen(3000);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.socket.on('connection', function(socket) {
socket.on('send message', function(data){
    io.socket.emit('new message', data);
});
});
```

What went wrong?

Comment: `io.socket` and `socket`, one or both are undefined, check them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `io.socket.on` should be `io.on`.
2. `io.socket.emit` should be `socket.emit`.

As in:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('send message', function(data){
    socket.emit('new message', data);
  );
});
```